# ArrayList size becomes 0 inside onClick

Tags: java, android

```
 public void confirmDelete(final ArrayList<Rec> list,final String d){

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure, You wanted to delete "+list.size()+" item(s)?");
    System.out.println("list size " + list.size());
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    VaravuSelavu userDB = new VaravuSelavu(getBaseContext());
                    System.out.println("list size "+ list.size()+ " "+d);
                    if (userDB.deleteIncome(list, d))
                    {
                        re=userDB.displayIncome(dateView.getText().toString());
                        if (re != null) {
                            incomeAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(re, getBaseContext());
                            incomeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
```

I want to pass the list inside the deleteIncome method.. the first print statement shows the correct size of the list... but inside the onClick method,the list size becomes 0... How to access the ArrayList inside onClick?

Comment: Are you sure no other code is emptying the list?  Don't forget that the `onClick()` isn't called immediately after the first SOP.

Comment: kindly add complete code, I think your list is gettings clear somehow, maybe getting reference of new list.